# Instance annotations in KITTI-360 2D instacne datasets

Tags: kitti

I am trying to count the instance of the vehicle in each image in KITTI-360 instance segmented dataset. For a trial, I first tried to do it on the single image. But I am getting only one instance value when I run my code. Which means that all the instances of the vehicle class are denoted by only one value in the image. I have attached the code that I used for finding this below.

I want to know why this is? or if I am doing something wrong in my code?

"""
This file is for the verification of the instance confirmation for the pixel values

```js
"""
This file is for the verification of the instance confirmation for the pixel values 

"""

#Imports 
import os
import numpy as np
import cv2
import json

# Import image from the file location
CWD = os.getcwd()
print(CWD)
instance_folder = os.path.join(CWD, 'image_my_data', "instance")
print(instance_folder)
instance_image_path =  os.path.join(instance_folder, "0000004402.png")
print(instance_image_path)
instance_image_array = cv2.imread(instance_image_path)

# print the size of the image for reference
print(instance_image_array.shape)

# Following are pixel values are measured and wanted to see what are the instance values at these pixel locations.

# Pixel location as tuples
pixel_location_1 = (210, 815)
pixel_location_2 = (200, 715)


# print the pixel location, for the above values
print('pixel values at (210, 815)', instance_image_array[pixel_location_1[0], pixel_location_1[1]])
print('pixel values at (200, 715)', instance_image_array[pixel_location_2[0], pixel_location_2[1]])
```

Note: the values of the pixels that I have taken above I choose by opening the image in paint and noting down the pixel coordinates in x and y in any locations where I can physically see that the two separate instances of the class are present.

Hope someone is able to help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my own question. The easiest way to find the instance in an image is to read the image using the cv2.imread(image, cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH)

The reason for doing this is, the KITTI-360 images are 8 bit images. So, we can use the regular imread for reading the image as a RGB image but that will not give the correct instance ids. When using the method above will convert the image into a single channel read and that single channel will contain the instance ids of each object.

I hope this helps someone else.